# Performing IO operations within java.util.function.Predicate

Tags: java

I have a question on the use of IO operations within java.util.function.Predicate. Please consider the following example:

```
public class ClientGroupFilter implements Predicate<Client> {

    private GroupMapper mapper;
    private List<String> validGroupNames = new ArrayList<>(); 

    public ClientGroupFilter(GroupMapper mapper) {
        this.mapper = mapper;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean test(Client client) {
        // this is a database call
        Set<Integer> validsIds = mapper.getValidIdsForGroupNames(validGroupNames);    
        return client.getGroupIds().stream().anyMatch(validIds::contains);
    }

    public void permit(String name) {
        validGroupNames.add(name);
    }
}
```

As you can see this filter accepts any number of server group names, which are resolved by the mapper when a specific client is tested. If the client owns one of the valid server groups, true is returned.

Now, of course it is obivous that this is totally iniffecient if the filter is applied to multiple clients. So, refactoring lead me to this:

```
public class ClientGroupFilter implements Predicate<Client> {

    private GroupMapper mapper;
    private List<String> validGroupNames = new ArrayList<>(); 
    private boolean updateRequired = true;
    private Set<Integer> validIds = new HashSet<>();

    public ClientGroupFilter(GroupMapper mapper) {
        this.mapper = mapper;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean test(Client client) {
        if(updateRequired) {
            // this is a database call
            validIds = mapper.getValidIdsForGroupNames(validGroupNames); 
            updateRequired = false;   
        }
        return client.getGroupIds().stream().anyMatch(validIds::contains);
    }

    public void permit(String name) {
        validGroupNames.add(name);
        updateRequired = true;
    }
}
```

The performance is a lot better, of course, but im still not happy with the solution, since i feel like java.util.function.Predicate should not be used like this. However, i still want to be able to provide a fast solution to filter a list of clients, without the need to require the consumer to map the server group name to its ids.

Does anyone have a better idea to refactor this?

Comment: Since the IO is entirely in the `Set<Integer> validsIds = mapper.getValidIdsForGroupNames(validGroupNames);` line, which doesn't depend upon the `client` input, why not just construct the predicate with that `Set` in the first place? (Or do it in the `permit` method)

Comment: @AndyTurner I guess thats a very good idea, thanks a lot for your help! If you would add that as a solution i could mark it as correct.

Comment: You seem to be relying on a vague, generalized opinion about how `Predicate`s should be implemented.  It is not serving you well, else you would not have asked the question.  I urge you to sit down and reason out why and under what circumstances you think a `Predicate` should avoid I/O.  FWIW, although I'd certainly agree that `Predicate`s rarely have a valid reason to perform I/O, I flatly reject the proposition that no conceivable `Predicate` should ever perform I/O.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I aggree with you, however, the reason i thought so is beacuse there is extra logic needed to prevent multiple calls to Predicate#test to perform poorly.

Comment: Well, @Glains, I took your *feeling* that "java.util.function.Predicate should not be used like this" to be tied instances performing I/O, even if only at their construction.  Do not trust your feelings about code unless you can support them with reasoning.  Think it through.

Comment: I agree, this does look like a weird implementation of a `Predicate`. Normally it would be just a simple lambda or a method reference, not a full-blown object with mutable state. Why don't you extract all that database querying and caching logic into a separate object and let your `Stream` expression use a simple predicate that calls into it? That would be a good move towards a separation of concerns.

Comment: To find whether two collections intersect, you don’t need Streams at all.  You can just do `return client.getGroupIds().removeAll(validIds);`, or, if your Client class doesn’t implement defensive copying, you can do `return new HashSet<Integer>(client.getGroupIds()).removeAll(validIds);`.  The remove and retain methods of Collection return true if and only if the Collection changed as a result of the operation.

Comment: @VGR _Finding whether_ two collections intersect is a much cheaper operation than computing the actual intersection. OP is doing it the right way.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Point taken, but I can’t help thinking that the lookups incurred by repeated calls to validIds.contains will mean the overall operation is not significantly cheaper.

Comment: @VGR That would be solved by keeping them in a HashSet instead of a list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your usage pattern is such that you call `permit` several times, and then use `Predicate<Client>` without calling `permit` again, you can separate the code that collects `validGroupNames` from the code of your predicate by using a builder:

```
class ClientGroupFilterBuilder {
    private final GroupMapper mapper;
    private List<String> validGroupNames = new ArrayList<>(); 
    public ClientGroupFilter(GroupMapper mapper) {
        this.mapper = mapper;
    }
    public void permit(String name) {
        validGroupNames.add(name);
    }
    public Predicate<Client> build() {
        final Set<Integer> validIds = mapper.getValidIdsForGroupNames(validGroupNames);
        return new Predicate<Client>() {
            @Override
            public boolean test(Client client) {
                return client.getGroupIds().stream().anyMatch(validIds::contains);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This restricts building of `validIds` to the point where we construct the `Predicate<Client>`. Once the predicate is constructed, no further input is necessary.